# Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug get 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebug

If I use Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug - I get very often (80%) 502 bad gateway.
If i change to Zend_Db_Profiler - it's ok, but is very interesting why Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug get error.

Code

```
$this->bootstrap('db');
$profiler = new Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug('All DB Queries');
$profiler->setEnabled(true);
$this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter()->setProfiler($profiler);
```

Off course problem is only in firefox with firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the problem of nginx with the Wildfire protocol headers.

See this
[Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error ONLY in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704626/nginx-502-bad-gateway-error-only-in-firefox)
The proposed solution given there is to change the nginx configuration to increase buffer size

```
proxy_buffers 8 16k;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;
```

Bug database of FirePHP Project 
https://code.google.com/p/firephp/issues/detail?id=128

Comment: For me, `proxy_buffers` weren't enough. I had to use `fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;`. Thanks for the link!